# Redirect to MVC Controller from Angular service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an MVC application where I am using the MVC controller to handle logging in and logging out.  When I attempt to log out, I call the LogOff action on my MVC Account controller which redirects to the Login action on this controller.  I have no problem calling this code and the Login action appears to run successfully.  However, the last line of this action is

```
return View();
```

I can see my screen flash as if it is drawing a new page.  However, I can still see http://localhost:60847/#/home in my browser instead of http://localhost:60847/Account/Login.

Is there something I need to add to the routing to allow it to handle MVC addresses?  Currently, my routing is the following:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    //controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "app/layout/home.html"
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up in several places and concluded that one option for fixing this issue was to call this action only from a hyperlink and include target="_self".  I can still add a ng-click attribute on the hyperlink and call code in my angular controller.  This is not quite what I wanted to do because I wanted to make the call from my angular controller instead of from the hyperlink, but it will work.

The code I used is as follows:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ul data-ng-controller="accountController as acctCtrl">
        <li><a data-ng-click="acctCtrl.logout()" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" target="_self">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```